# Output difference with successive RSA encryption and base64 encoding in php and ruby

Tags: php, ruby, base64, escaping, rsa

My goal is to integrate an [API service](https://docs.cashfree.com/docs/ip-whitelisting) which wants me to generate a signature by following these steps.

1. Retrieve your clientId.
2. Append this with CURRENT UNIX timestamp separated by a period (.)
3. Encrypt this data using RSA encrypt with Public key you received – this is the signature.
4. Pass this signature through the header X-Cf-Signature.

Step 3 is the signature generation step. In my ruby application this is how I have implemented the steps.

```
def dynamic_signature
 raw_data = "#{client_id}.#{Time.now.to_i}"
 filepath = "public_key.pem"
 public_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new File.read(filepath)
 Base64.strict_encode64(public_key.public_encrypt(raw_data)).encode("UTF-8")
end
```

But the API service rejects this signature. They have code snippet examples in php so tried this process in php with the following code. I have used the variables from the ruby code above for representation.

```
<?php

$plainData = <raw_data>;
$publicKey = <public_key.to_s>;
openssl_public_encrypt($plainData, $encrypted, $publicKey, OPENSSL_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);
echo base64_encode($encrypted);

?>
```

This signature gets accepted by the API service.
I did some manual inspection and both base64 outputs were obviously different. In ruby I have tried with and without enforcing an `encode("UTF-8")`.

Interestingly the following statement returns true, no matter if I do a `strict_encode64` or `encode64` or append `encode("UTF-8")` at the end.

```
base64_generated_in_ruby.bytes == base64_generated_in_php.bytes
```

I did this equality check by copy pasting the base64 encoded strings in the ruby console.

I suspect base64 encoding is working differently for escape characters in both these languages. Any help is appreciated.

Edit 1: Adding an example.

1. RSA encrypted string that I'm encoding in base64.

```
"g\xF3\f%\xA2\xC0(\xCBYAw\x80\xA5 c\x9DR\xC7r\xFE\xAF \xADJ\xCBy\x8D\xC8kd#\xD3\x04L(\x9B\xC0V\n\xCD\xFF\xD4\rj\xF0\x12\x86\xEC5\xC6ev\xCEUD\x9B\xA2\xAD\x9F{\xC8\xF5\x8A\x00->\xB5\xA4f\x05\x9F\xE1\x81u\xB5\x87\xD4\xD7\xA7\xCC\xE0:\xC9\xF3,\x8D(\x10\xEC\\\xE8'\r\xFA\x14\x82\x8A\xCF_^\xAA\x94\x17\x15\xD0Qw\x18\xDB\xE7\t\xEEy\x9E04\x94\xDE\xFB\xF6\xEB:\xDF\x90\xDER\xEB\xF1c\xF2\x98\x00\x9CM\x16\xA6{\x12\xA8\xA2\xE7\x00\x89\xDE\xB4\x9C\xB1\xE9\x81\x9D\xB4\xC8~q\x8A\xBDu#\xD2\xD2\x19T\xE4H\x7F\x0E\xDF\xECV\x8E\rF\xF7\x12m\x1C\xFE-\xC2gO\x90\xEDp\x88\x1A\x1D\t4\xC2\r!\xD5Y\xC3\xBB\xB8*B%\x00\xDF\xE2s\x8A\x19j\xFB\xEBy\xD7\xD6\xF5\x06\x99\xEE\xEA\xE4\xA3\x83\x97\xDB\x95\xA2o\x86\x97c\xA8w\xAAb\xEF\x00e\xC4\b\xD3\xEB\xFB\x86\xF4\xE2!\xF1{\xA5\x80\xD7\xC4\xC4\x01,\xBFj-"
```

2. Using ruby as `Base64.strict_encode64(rsa_string)`

```
"Z/MMJaLAKMtZQXeApSBjnVLHcv6vIK1Ky3mNyGtkI9METCibwFYKzf/UDWrwEobsNcZlds5VRJuirZ97yPWKAC0+taRmBZ/hgXW1h9TXp8zgOsnzLI0oEOxc6CcN+hSCis9fXqqUFxXQUXcY2+cJ7nmeMDSU3vv26zrfkN5S6/Fj8pgAnE0WpnsSqKLnAInetJyx6YGdtMh+cYq9dSPS0hlU5Eh/Dt/sVo4NRvcSbRz+LcJnT5DtcIgaHQk0wg0h1VnDu7gqQiUA3+Jzihlq++t519b1Bpnu6uSjg5fblaJvhpdjqHeqYu8AZcQI0+v7hvTiIfF7pYDXxMQBLL9qLQ=="
```

3. Using php as `base64_encode($rsa_string)`

```
"Z/MMJaLAKMtZQXeApSBjnVLHcv6vIK1Ky3mNyGtkI9METCibwFYKzf/UDWrwEobsNcZlds5VRJuirZ97yPWKAC0+taRmBZ/hgXW1h9TXp8zgOsnzLI0oEOxc6CcN+hSCis9fXqqUFxXQUXcY2+cJ7nmeMDSU3vv26zrfkN5S6/Fj8pgAnE0WpnsSqKLnAInetJyx6YGdtMh+cYq9dSPS0hlU5Eh/Dt/sVo4NRvcSbRz+LcJnT5DtcIgaHQk0wg0h1VnDu7gqQiUA3+Jzihlq++t519b1Bpnu6uSjg5fblaJvhpdjqHeqYu8AZcRcYtPr+4b04iHxe6WA18TEASy/ai0="
```

Comment: could you please show the two base64 encoded strings. Base64 just encodes bytes and doesn't care for encoding.

Comment: It's been a while since I've done Ruby, but shouldn't it be `raw_data = "#{client_id}.#{Time.now.to_i}"`? You're missing the second `#`.

Comment: @jps I've added an example.

Comment: @Sammitch sorry that was just a typo here, I've fixed, it's written correctly on the code.

Comment: The way that the outputs match until the last bit makes me think that you might have a padding mismatch. Since the PHP version is accepted it's likely that there's a missing option in the `public_encrypt()` in your Ruby code.

Comment: I just converted the base64 string to hex and there's only very little difference: `67f30c25a2c028cb59417780a520639d52c772feaf20ad4acb798dc86b6423d3044c289bc0560acdffd40d6af01286ec35c66576ce55449ba2ad9f7bc8f58a002d3eb5a466059fe18175b587d4d7a7cce03ac9f32c8d2810ec5ce8270dfa14828acf5f5eaa941715d0517718dbe709ee799e303494defbf6eb3adf90de52ebf163f298009c4d16a67b12a8a2e70089deb49cb1e9819db4c87e718abd7523d2d21954e4487f0edfec568e0d46f7126d1cfe2dc2674f90ed70881a1d0934c20d21d559c3bbb82a422500dfe2738a196afbeb79d7d6f50699eeeae4a38397db95a26f869763a877aa62ef0065c40  8d3ebfb86f4e221f17ba580d7c4c4012cbf6a2d`

Comment: and the second one: `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`

Comment: @sammitch so the base64 encoded string in the example I added also gets rejected. Only the signature generated in the php code-block gets accepted. This indicates the combination of rsa and base64 are also different. Since the example php base64 also gets rejected that means the rsa output is also different.

Comment: there's only a difference in two bytes in the hex code, and the first string has one byte less. I have just no idea what causes this little difference.

Comment: @sammitch I had a padding mismatch. I have fixed it now. Thanks you so much!

Comment: If this is fixed can you please either answer your own question (if you think it is useful to others) or remove it?

Answer (score 0):

The ruby `public_encrypt` method does not include a padding argument by default. Use `public_encrypt(raw_data, OpenSSL::PKey::RSA::PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING)` to add the relevant padding argument. In the supplied php code submitted padding is explicitly mentioned.